# Python JSON append

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to find out how to format my json file for my puprose.

My json file looks like this (pulled from sql db):

```
[
    {
        "type": "xy",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short": "xy",
        "product": "simple",
        "amount": "4"
    },
]
```

what I am trying to achive is something like this:

```
[
{
  "products":**   {
        "type": "N1001",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short": "xy",
        "product": "simple",
        "amount": "4"
    }
}
]
```

how can I add {"products": at the beginning and } at the end of my json file?
So the main object is "products":

Thanks in advance!
Wayx

EDIT:

I'm trying to achive something like this:

```
[
{
  "products":   
{
        "type": "N1001",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short": "xy",
        "product": "simple",
        "amount": "4"
    },
{
        "type": "N1001",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short": "xy",
        "product": "simple",
        "amount": "4"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: this is unclear. Do you have actual json stored as text in your DB?

Comment: I'm pulling the data from an mssql database and generate a json file from that. That file is  does not meet my requirements, therefore i have to nest that json file so it would look something like this: {"products": jsonfile }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ao = array of object

```
ao = [ { "type": "xy", "view_code": "english", "short": "xy", "product": "simple", "amount": "4" }]

print(ao)
arr = []

for el in ao:
    vals = {}
    vals[el['product']]=el
    arr.append(vals)
    
print(arr)
```

where:

```
vals[el['product']]=el
```

is the value, which needs to be positioned as key.

---

Edit:

```
ao = [ { "type": "xy", "view_code": "english", "short": "xy", "product": "simple", "amount": "4" }, { "type": "xy", "view_code": "english", "short": "xy", "product": "simple", "amount": "4" }]

arr = {}
arr['products'] = ao
```

output:

```
{'products': [{'type': 'xy', 'view_code': 'english', 'short': 'xy', 'product': 'simple', 'amount': '4'}, {'type': 'xy', 'view_code': 'english', 'short': 'xy', 'product': 'simple', 'amount': '4'}]}
```

Comment: This code results in a list like `[{"simple": {...}}]` while the OP says they want `[{"products": {...}}]`

Comment: this answer gives the opportunity to understand concept, I underline the line: vals['products']=el
where the OP - freely can write, whatever he wants

Comment: Not quite the result i tried to achieve. {"products": and } as first object, the other objects from json should be nestet in "products":

Comment: @wayx i prepared code for that result:

Comment: @PiotrŻak thanks, any chance of removing the "[" and "]" in second array? from {"products": [ { to {"products": {

Comment: only in case, when there is only one object. if there are multiple products, then might be hold in array.

Comment: i have multiple objects wich should be under one object, what is the best approach?

Comment: got it, converted it into a string and back to json :D thank you!

Comment: so i figured that i actually need the first solution. wich gives me the error: KeyError: 'product'. Here is the code i am using: import json

arr = []

k = json.load(open('test.json'))

for el in k:
    vals = {}
    vals[el['product']] = el
    arr.append(vals)

print(arr)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a JSON file or a list of dictionaries? If you have a JSON file, you'll first want to load the JSON into Python datastructures like so:

```
import json

data = json.loads(my_string)
```

You can then do this:

```
new_data = [{"products": item} for item in data]
```

If you need to convert it back to JSON you can then do this:

```
my_string = json.dumps(new_data)
```